# ld can't find MKL library after adding it to ld.so.conf.d

Tags: fedora, ld

I'm trying to link a a library, `libmkl_rt.so`, while compiling Julia in Fedora 30. The library is located in `/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.4.243/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin/`.

Running `ld -lmkl_rt` results in "ld: cannot find -lmkl_rt"

Manually specifying the location works as expected:

`ld -L/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.4.243/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin -lmkl_rt` results in "ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; not setting start address"

I've tried adding this location to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable, which is empty by default, and I've tried creating a file within /etc/ld.so.conf.d called "mkl.conf" containing only the library's path, then running `ldconfig`. Neither of these allows ld to find the library.

How can I get ld to search this path?